# Why does UIWebView Not Scroll?

Tags: ios, ipad, uiwebview

I've looked at numerous questions similar to this but try as I might, I cannot get a `UIWebView` to scroll or interact in any way.  Here is the code:

```
- (void)loadView {
    [super loadView];

    ...

    [self.displayView loadHTMLString:entry->infoHtml baseURL:nil];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.displayView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    self.displayView.scrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = YES;
    self.displayView.scrollView.scrollEnabled = YES;
    [self.displayView.scrollView flashScrollIndicators];
}
```

The view appears, displays all the correct content, and shows the vertical scroll-bar for a second, correctly indicating the portion of the content currently displayed.

But I can't scroll it.  Touching the content and moving my finger around does nothing at all.  Interacting with a non-overlapping `UITableView` under the same parent works fine; touching entries there updates the contents of the `UIWebView` as it has been programmed to do.

The UIWebView was created in the Storyboard with these options:

- Scales Page To Fit: *unchecked*  (when checked, can't pinch-to-zoom, either)
- Pagination: *unpaginated*
- Mode: *Aspect Fit*  (tried several; all un-scrollable)
- UserInteractionEnabled: *checked*  (parent views also have this checked)

The view is fully visible.  I've tried making it significantly smaller than its parent and the displayed content always stops at the correct place.  There is no delegate or gesture recognizers for this view.

The containing view has a `UITableView` and a `UILabel`, neither of which overlap the area of the `UIWebView`.  I've tried changing the order of the views in the Scene on the storyboard but that also makes no difference.

I've tried removing the view from UIBuilder and creating it programmatically like so:

```
self.displayView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(400, 220, 400, 300)];
[self.view addSubview:self.displayView];
```

Same results.  I tried removing all other elements from the Scene except for this single programmatically created UIWebView.  Still the same results.

Elsewhere in my code, I've put a `UIWebView` as the `@"accessoryView"` of a `UIAlertView` and there I can scroll the content as expected.

*Is there something else that needs to be done to be able to scroll a UIWebView sub-view?*

**2014-04-20:** In fact, if I add the following lines to the bottom of my `-loadView` method, I get a dialog with the same HTML content as the window behind it, but I **am** able to scroll the dialog version.  The only difference I can think of is that the dialog is modal (forced focus) while my own window with both a `UITableView` and `UIWebView` still allows interaction with the views visible behind it.

```
UIWebView* contents = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 250, 250)];
[contents loadHTMLString:entry->infoHtml baseURL:nil];
[alertView setValue:contents forKey:@"accessoryView"];
[alertView show];
```

On the other hand, if I replace the last two lines of *that* with `[self.view addSubview:contents];` then I get the same second HTML view in the upper-left corner of the screen but that will **not** scroll.

Comment: Strange! I add UIWebView, it can scroll normally. Is the content of this webView is too short, it causes you can not scroll. Let's try add UIWebView in another project and test.

Comment: Have you verified that the HTML you are trying to use works if you run it in mobile safari?

Comment: I've tried several different HTML files, all of which display fine in browsers.  My UIWebView seems to like it, too, and displays the top portion of the file just fine.  I simply can't scroll it to see the later content.  If I make the font smaller or "scale to fit", then I can also see more (or all) of the file.

Comment: UIWebView scrolls based on its content size. So it might be possible that your webview is not able to get right content size. Can you post one of the HTML file to check? And can you also by loading any other web site in same web view that scrolling is working or not?

Comment: I tried many different HTML files.  The scroll fine in a real browser or in the Android App.  I even tried a simple file of `<p>X</p>` repeated for letters a-z.  It only shows the first few paragraphs with no ability to scroll.  Also, the scroll bar, when it "flashes" indicates that only the top part is being shown.

Comment: As a test, I added an alert-view dialog on top of my own compound view and inserted a `UIWebView` inside.  The same HTML content appears and is scrollable inside the dialog.  (see 2014-04-20 update in question)

Comment: `while my own window with both a UITableView and UIWebView still allows interaction with the views visible behind it.` Does that mean you have multiple windows? Or did you mean ViewControllers? You usually don't have multiple windows in an iOS application.

Comment: @HAS, I have a `UIView` which has three sub-views, a heading `UILabel`, a left-side `UITableView` with strings, and a right-side `UIWebView` that has its content set appropriately when I select different items from the table-view.  There is also a "close" `UIButton` in the corner.  Both the table and button function correctly.  The `UIWebView` is initially loaded with content as well as when I select an entry from the `UITableView`.  Both cases display correctly but I can't scroll it.  I have tried removing all other sub-views just in case there was some conflict but that didn't help.

Comment: @HAS, to completed that...  There is one Controller that handles the `UITableView` selection events and loads the desired content into the `UIWebView`.  The latter has no controller, delegate, whatever.

Comment: do you use Autolayout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've worked it out.  First, I tried adding this to `-viewDidLoad` in my MainController class:

```
UIWebView* contents = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 250, 250)];
[contents loadHTMLString:@"<html><head><title>FOO</title></head><body><p>A</p><p>B</p><p>C</p><p>D</p><p>E</p><p>F</p><p>G</p><p>H</p><p>I</p><p>J</p><p>K</p><p>L</p><p>M</p><p>N</p><p>O</p><p>P</p><p>Q</p><p>R</p><p>S</p><p>T</p><p>U</p><p>V</p><p>W</p><p>X</p><p>Y</p><p>Z</p></body></html>" baseURL:nil];
contents.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
[self.view addSubview:contents];
```

It displays but isn't scrollable.  I have a StartupController that deals with initializing the app and runs first so I added the same code there.  *This was scrollable!*  Ah-Ha!

It occurred to me that the top-level Google Map (`GMSMapView`) that covers the MainView might be swallowing the scroll events but passing click events.  Within the scene, instead of just a single map-view, I created a top-level plain/simple/empty `UIView` and made the `GMSMapView` a full-sized child of that.  Now when I add my views to that new top-level (simple) view, they are siblings rather than children of the map and get all events correctly.

As a result, my `UIWebView` is now scrollable.  Thanks for everybody's comments and suggestions!  It's been several months of on-and-off trying different things to finally figure that one out.

Comment: If anybody knows how to *trace* an event using XCode, let me know.  Perhaps then I would have been able to quickly see what was swallowing the scroll events.

Answer (score 0):

Please check that the web view is contained fully within the bounds of its parent view (and so on up the view hierarchy).  An easy way to do this is to set some background colors.  Possibly you have some constraints that aren't behaving as you expect.

Similarly, that all parent views are user-interaction-enabled.

**Edit**:  I understand that the web view is fully visible.  But that doesn't mean it is contained within the bounds of its superview.  If the superview has clipsToBounds=NO (default, I believe) then any subview outside its bounds will be visible but will not receive touches.

Comment: I stated clearly in my question that the view is fully visible.  I've tried showing it many ways, including through the storyboard and programmatically, with various sizes and borders.  I also stated that user interaction is enabled in the parent views, the latter demonstrated by the adjacent UITableView accepting touch events.

Comment: I understand - and I saw that.  But a subview may be fully visible (but not receive touches) if it is contained outside the bounds of its parent (and clipsToBounds=NO, the default...).  I'll update my answer with this information.  Thanks for the downvote.